# How to solve "your connection was interrupted err_network_changed" error?

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, internet-connection, administration

I have a problem connecting to my home network wirelessly, and so far I have tried almost everything. When connected, I get a yellow sign on the wi-fi icon, and an

> err_network_changed

message in browser. I am using two laptops on the same network and one works fine, but the second one is is causing problems.
Here is some information about my machine and things that I have tried so far:

- Laptop - Dell Inspiron N5100
- Windows 10 Pro (Version 1803) OS

Tried:

- Online search
- Flushing DNS
- Resetting router
- Winsock reset
- TCP/IP settings reset
- Re-installing drivers
- Searching for official Dell wireless drivers, but
  can't find them for Windows 10. I've tried Windows 7 but no luck.
- Disabling Ethernet
- Disabling/enabling wireless connection
- Using Google's DNS
- Changing IP to static.
- Windows full reset

I doubt it is a hardware problem, because I have been connected to home network and it all worked fine but suddenly this happened. Note that I have no problem connecting to any other network, but for some reason can't connect to the one at home. I've also looked at wireless statistics for my router and I see that package receiving is very low.

Here is some additional info from IP Configuration: [image]

I am using the TP-Link WR740N router.
Any suggestion or link to a solution is very helpful, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with my wireless configuration in router, my channel was set to **"auto"**, therefore router was assigning wireless channel automatically and thus causing the interference with another near by access point, i was able to solve it by changing the option.
See [how to change wifi channel](https://help.teksavvy.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000130943-How-to-change-your-Wireless-Channel-D-Link-TP-Link-Linksys-CISCO-or-SmartRG-)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Ethernet cable connected one end in desktop and other is free would also cause the change in internet connection

Comment: Strangely, this was the problem for me! The issue went away after disconnecting the ethernet cable.

Answer (score 0):

I think your WiFi connection is unstable, but there isn't enough information in your question to prove that theory. When you get an 'error: network changed', it is a sign that Windows has registered that the network interface has gone up or down (possibly briefly). Here are a couple things you can try:

- What is the signal strength reported in windows? Do conditions
  improve when you move closer to your router?
- Does your issue coincide with interference (i.e. use of microwave
  oven)?
- Are you using wireless repeaters? I find these to be incredibly
  unreliable.
- If you ping your router indefinitely (e.g. ping 192.168.1.1 -t), do
  you see a lot of packet loss? Are the packet counts on your router
  and computer in close agreement? Does your router list/count packet
  errors, and is this number at least an order of magnitude lower than
  the successful packet count?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue for a long time in Ubuntu 18.04 (Your connection was interrupted / Network Change error). How to fix it.

1. Check Network Settings (Disable IPV6). Further you can execute the following code:

   sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
   and add the following code

   #disable ipv6

   net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1

   net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1

   net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1

   net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 1
2. Check your wifi router. If your laptop supports only 2.4GHz, then disable 5GHz or vice versa. Sometimes, your laptop may toggle between these two GHz speeds.
3. Check if you are using the docker container.
4. Optional - Laptop driver issues mainly